# My react app and express server are on different ports

Tags: reactjs, express

Problem/error:
I am running my react app on port 3000 and express on 3001.

error: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/api' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
//react code 
//this function gets called when a button get pressed
...
post = () => {
  const client_data = {info: this.state.input};
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json
    },
    
    body: JSON.stringify(client_data)
  }

  fetch("http://localhost:3001/api", options);
}
...
```

Server is pretty simple

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('api', (request, response)=>{console.log(request})
```

(when I add "app.listen(3000)" react stops working)

Comment: It should be app.listen(3001)

Comment: ok but how do I create a bridge/tunnel between react and express

Comment: since CORS won't let me

Comment: you need to enable cors on your express server. That is industry standard. You need to allow requests from your react app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Brief explanation:

When developing react app, react creates a live developing enviroment that runs on `-p 3000`. However, if I spin up a node backend on `-p 3000`, the ports collide and the live enviroment crashes.

## Solution:

### Spin the node backend on a different port `(4000)`

### and make a proxy in the live app

```
SERVER:
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is up on -p 4000")
```

```
CLIENT:
In the react app package.json file insert this key/value:
{
...
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to proxy your requests from react to express. The best way is to let it do your WebPack devServer, having this configuration:

(I assume, your express server is on 3000 and your React app on 3001)

```
devServer: {
    ...
    ...
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/',
      },
    },
```

This says, that whichever request to path `/api` will be redirected to port 3001. Then you fetch to

```
fetch("/api", options);
```

Client automatically requests localhost:3001 (port on which the application is running), but the proxy redirects to 3000.